# Get records using start and end LocalDate parameters

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, localdate

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Login> login;
}


public class Login {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private LocalDateTime loginTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findAll();

    // List<User> List<User> findByLogin_LoginTimeGreaterThanEqualAndLogin_LoginTimeLessThanEqual(@Param("loginTime") LocalDate start, @Param("loginTime") LocalDate end);    }
```

I want to find all the unique users where the `dateTime` is greater than or equal to the provided `start` param value and less than or equal to the provided `end` param value.

**http://localhost:8080/api/users?start=YYYYMMDD&end=YYMMDD**

---

When I tried

```
curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/hal+json' -d '2018-06-19' 'http://localhost:8080/test/user/search/findAllByLogin_LoginTimeGreaterThanEqualAndLogin_LoginTimeLessThanEqual
```

I get

> "Value must not be null!"

I'm using 1.5.4-RELEASE